# Spring Data Rest and integration testing

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I'm writing some tests in order to test my application. I'm using Spring Boot 2.0.2.

Image the following sitution with
the following entity

```
@Entity
public class Board extends BaseEntity {

    @Column(length = 128)
    @NotNull
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "board")
    private Set<Activity> activities;

    ... ...
}
```

and the following repository

```
@Repository
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface BoardRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Board, Long> {}
```

Now the first step of the test that I want to do is to create a Board object, so my test starts with the following code

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.post;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class BoardControllerRestIT {

    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate testRestTemplate;
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;


    @Test
    public void testBoardCreation() throws Exception {
        Board b = new Board();
        b.setName("gianni");

        String responseFromTestRestTemplate = testRestTemplate.postForObject("/crud/boards", b, String.class);
        assertNotNull(responseFromTestRestTemplate);


        ResultActions resultActions = mockMvc.perform(
                post("/crud/boards")
                        .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(b))
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
        resultActions.andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().is2xxSuccessful());
        resultActions.andDo(mvcResult -> {
            String responseFromMockMvc = mvcResult.getResponse().getContentAsString();
        });
    }
}
```

The problem is that, the responseFromTestRestTemplate variable is filled with the usual spring data rest response. 
Instead inside the responseFromMockMvc variable, the body is empty.

I want to use the mockMvc solution only because is more effective from the tests point of view, but without the body is impossible to go on.
The approach with the testRestTemplate was only an attemp to understand what's going on.

What I'm doing wrong?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

My guess is whatever your controller is doing or constraints on your entity, is preventing you from creating the same exact object twice.

Try the following changes:

Instead of:

```
Board b = new Board();
b.setName("gianni");

String responseFromTestRestTemplate = testRestTemplate.postForObject("/crud/boards", b, String.class);
```

Do:

```
Board b = new Board();
b.setName("gianni");

String responseFromTestRestTemplate = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(b);
```

The way you're only calling `POST /crud/boards` once and that's via `mockMvc`.